# Android onMenuItemClick() - detect which menu clicked?

Tags: android, button, view, menu, popup

I'm currently writing a simple application that uses 2 buttons anchored with Pop Up Menus that will display when the button is pressed. That was simple enough, however i'm having trouble with onMenuItemClick() method, which I want to use to change the text of the button to the menu item that was clicked.

Since I have two Pop Up Menus, each with 3 items, does this mean I would have to write 6 different if statements in the onMenuItemClick(), each one attempting to detect which item from which menu was clicked? Or is there a more simple way of doing this, for example specifying 2 onMenuItemClick() methods, each linked to the separate 2 menus?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMenuItemClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void showColourPopUpMenu(View v){
        PopupMenu coloursPopUpMenu = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        coloursPopUpMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        coloursPopUpMenu.inflate(R.menu.colours_menu);
        coloursPopUpMenu.show();
    }

    public void showShapePopUpMenu(View v){
        PopupMenu shapesPopUpMenu = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        shapesPopUpMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        shapesPopUpMenu.inflate(R.menu.shape_menu);
        shapesPopUpMenu.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        //How to determine which menu clicked?
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can go for switch statement...please refer the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible directly. You'd at least need to map the item ids `item.getItemId()` to the menu (button) they're connected to.

Maybe a little simpler might be using groups like: *menu/colours_menu.xml*

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <group android:id="@+id/colours_menu" >
        <item android:id="@+id/item1" ... />
        <item android:id="@+id/item2" ... />
        <item android:id="@+id/item3" ... />
    </group>
</menu>
```

With `item.getGroupId()` you'd get the group ids and only need to map these to the buttons:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getGroupId() == R.id.colours_menu) {
        // edit colors menu
    } else {
        // edit shape menu
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId()
    switch(id) {
     case R.id.item1:
          return true;
     case R.id.item2:
          return true;
     default:
          return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Create the listener when asigning it.

```
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        return true;
    }
});
```